# Changing default error messages in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Our client has decided that they would like all blank AR error messages to be changed from "can't be blank" to "must be completed" throughout the entire app.

What's the easiest Rails'y way of doing this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `config/locales/en.yml`

Specifically, put the following in that file:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      messages:
        blank: "must be completed"
```