# Change validation error message globally in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

I'm looking for a clean way to change a validation failure message globally throughout all models, all attributes, etc.. in a Ruby on Rails 3 application.  Something like changing "can't be blank" to "is required".

I already found out about the locale file but I'd rather not have to add each attribute of each model in the application to a list and then have to maintain it.  It sounds way too complicated for something so seemingly simple.

Is there a good way of doing this?

Comment: Rails allows setting the default global error messages in the config locale file.  See answers to these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808361/where-are-default-validation-error-messages-in-rails-3-0 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538212/changing-default-error-messages-in-rails

Comment: Thanks.. thats what I was looking for.  Didn't think to use those search terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noah Miller provided the answer to my question in the comments..

It seems this question is a duplicate of:

[Where are Default Validation Error Messages in Rails 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808361/where-are-default-validation-error-messages-in-rails-3-0)

and

[Changing default error messages in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538212/changing-default-error-messages-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

There is a [project](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n) to i18n rails. You can follow the instructions in their page or simply download your preferred locale [yaml](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale).

This will solve your problem with *Can't be blank* and all the future problems that you will have with the language.

Comment: @user2112648 The project solve perfectly the issue that you were having, and it is not my project.